# Return an Observable by using a Storage value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise, rxjs, observable

I'm quite new with Ionic, and Django, but I'm trying my best.
I'm currently struggling with something, and I would like to have good practice before implementing weird stuff everywhere in my project.

I have a Django backend, which returns a JSON object as follow, on GET /users/{username} :

```
{
"id":3,
"username":"admin",
"email":"admin@example.com",
"is_active":true,
"date_joined":"2021-04-24T14:05:33.724350Z"
}
```

With following functions :
api.service.ts

```
getInfo() {       
        return from(Storage.get({ key: CURRENT_USERNAME }).then(data => {
            const userName = data.value
            console.log("url : " + `${environment.api_url}/users/${userName}`)
            return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.api_url}/users/${userName}`)
        })
        )
    }
```

profile.page.ts

```
async getInfo() {
    this.apiService.getInfo().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("my data stringified " + JSON.stringify(data))
        data.subscribe(data2 => {
          console.log("data 2 json " + JSON.stringify(data2))
        })
      },
      err => {
        // Set the error information to display in the template
        console.log(`An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`)
      }
    );
```

Sevaral questions :

- Am I right using a Storage object to store the username ? Or should I not bother, and use a global variable, which would simplify the whole code.
- As you can see in my profile.page.ts, the code is promise into observable which is quite horrible to read and I'm pretty sure not optimized. But, I didn't find any way to return the correct information in my api.service.ts getInfo() method. I wanted to assign a variable to the value of my CURRENT_USERNAME, but without using a global variable, I don't achieve to.

Thank you! Any tips, good practice, and advice would be much appreciated.

Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think keeping the username in storage is a good option. You could change it to such, that whenever the app is initialized, you fetch the username from the storage and assign it to variable, for example an observable you can then subscribe to in the components, so that you don't need to fetch it from storage every time you need it.

As for your code you currently have, I would make some modification to make it better. It's not recommended to nest subscriptions, but you can use `switchMap` to chain requests. So maybe try something like this:

Service:

```ts
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ....

getInfo() {       
    return from(Storage.get({ key: CURRENT_USERNAME })).pipe(
       switchMap(data => {
         const username = data.value;
         return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.api_url}/users/${userName}`)
       })
    );
}
```

And component (shortened):

```ts
getInfo() {
  this.apiService.getInfo().subscribe(data => {
     // do stuff with http-response
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the details.
Thanks for switchMap. I've seen it a few times in tutorial etc, but wasn't sure how to use it. I've read a bit of doc (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), but as I'm newbie to Angular, I wasn't clear on this. 
So basically, switchMap are used to convert any kind of map to a new Observable<Object> object, is that correct ?